# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/hibernate/cfg/Configuration;
```

Configuration

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.techy9</groupId>
<artifactId>techy9CustomerService</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-TECHY9CUSTOMERSERVICE</version>
<name>techy9CustomerService Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring-context which provides core functionality -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The spring-aop module provides an AOP Alliance-compliant aspect-oriented 
        programming implementation allowing you to define -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The spring-webmvc module (also known as the Web-Servlet module) contains 
        Spring’s model-view-controller (MVC) and REST Web Services implementation 
        for web applications -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- The spring-web module provides basic web-oriented integration features 
        such as multipart file upload functionality and the initialization of the 
        IoC container using Servlet listeners and a web-oriented application context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>


      <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->  
      <dependency>  
       <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>  
       <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>  
       <version>1.2.2</version>  
      </dependency>  

      <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->  
      <dependency>  
       <groupId>commons-io</groupId>  
       <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>  
       <version>1.3.2</version>  
      </dependency>  

      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.7.ga</version>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>  
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>  
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>  
       <version>5.1.34</version>  
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>




</dependencies>
<build>
<finalName>techy9CustomerService</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: This could be a dependency issue. add your pom.xml file

Comment: I added pom.xml ,please help me out

Comment: First never mix versions of a framework regardless which framework. You are mixing Spring jars from different versions (2.0.8 and 4.1.6) and you are also mixing hibernate versions (4.3.11 and 3.2.7). fix those versions

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following from `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.7.ga</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.8</version>
   </dependency>
```

Keep the following as it is.

```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
       <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
   </dependency>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't advise people to use the old `com.springsource` bundles. Adding the `hibernate-entitymanager` dependency is enough.

Comment: Getting "Missing artifact javax.persistence:com.springsource.javax.persistence:jar:2.0.0" by doing above changes

Comment: still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

In your pom there are conflicting versions of multiple frameworks and you also have duplicated dependencies

**Version Mixing**

1. Spring: 4.1.6 and 2.0.8
2. Hibernate 4.3.11.Final and 3.2.7.ga

** Duplicated**
1. JUnit
2. javax.mail

Neither of those jars is compatible with the newer (or vice versa).

I would strongly suggest to use the [Spring IO Platform](http://platform.spring.io/platform/) as that will manage dependencies for you and saves you searching for compatible versions.

For this to work add the following to your pom.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and remove the duplication and mixed versions and the version numbers all together. This should leave you with a pom similar to something like the one below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.techy9</groupId>
  <artifactId>techy9CustomerService</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-TECHY9CUSTOMERSERVICE</version>
  <name>techy9CustomerService Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- spring-context which provides core functionality -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- The spring-aop module provides an AOP Alliance-compliant aspect-oriented 
    programming implementation allowing you to define -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- The spring-webmvc module (also known as the Web-Servlet module) contains 
    Spring’s model-view-controller (MVC) and REST Web Services implementation 
    for web applications -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>techy9CustomerService</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: i removed spring-support and im using spring-context-support 4.1.6

Comment: That dependency is already pulled in, the `javax.mail` dependencies are declared twice remove one of them (as I did in the sample above).